# retrive second highest point from table with no unique column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have one table named users. In this table i have one column named credits(not unique).
Now i want the second highest user accroding to the users credits. If the credits field is unique thenmy below query is working fine

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY credits DESC LIMIT 1 , 1
```

But , if the users credit is not unique then its create problem for retrive me data
suppose,

```
mack has 200 credits
jack has 200 credits
rock has 150 credits
```

when i has this types of record then,in output of this query i want the **rock** record not **jack**

can anyone help me to find out the correct value ?

thanks in advance

Comment: How about if there was another entry like `sack has 150 credits` too? Would you want rock or sack? Or does it not matter?

Comment: i want both stack and rock record with single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT credits
            FROM users
            ORDER BY credits desc
            LIMIT 1,1
        ) b ON a.credits = b.credits
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ada4b/2)

Comment: its working perfectly fine ... its this what i want thanks john woo

Comment: Wait. This doesn't in fact work fine. Try with four records: 300, 200, 150, 150

Comment: @Abhilash if that's the case, its 200 that will be the second highest. And the user want's the second highest right?

Comment: I know. But the resultset shown is: 200, 150, 150. Try with 200, 200, 150, 120. The resultset is 150, 120. Not what was asked...

Comment: i check all the cases like first ( 300, 200, 150, 150), second(300,300,570,570,500,500) third(710,710,570,500,500) in all above cases its working perfect... i dont have single issue. thanks john woo

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps (first get `second highest credits` then find the `users having those that credit and`select one  from the top`. This will retrieve **one user having second highest credit**):

```
     SELECT * FROM users
     WHERE credits = (SELECT distinct credits FROM users 
                   ORDER BY credits DESC LIMIT 1,1)
     LIMIT 1;
```

**EDIT:** If you also want to select within users having same score then use the appropriate filter/sorting condition e.g. to select `rock` between `rock` and `jenni`, you could have another ordering base on name(assuming name is the column having names)

```
     SELECT * FROM users
     WHERE credits = (SELECT distinct credits FROM users 
                   ORDER BY credits DESC LIMIT 1,1)
     ORDER name desc 
     LIMIT 1;
```

To get both `rock` and `jenni`, just remove the limit from the end and update the inner limit e.g:

```
     SELECT * FROM users
     WHERE credits = (SELECT distinct credits FROM users 
                   ORDER BY credits DESC LIMIT 1, 1);
```

Comment: yep.. its working fine but still have problem  mack has 200 credits
jack has 200 credits
rock has 150 credits jeni has 150 credits then from your query in output it shows me jeni's record... will you tell me how do i get the rock's record or both jeni and rock record with single query

Comment: @deckjohn: That is why I mentioned, one user :). Please refer the updated answer for this specific data scenario. Let me know, if doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't the subquery return more than one row and fail?

Comment: @Abhilash: Yes, I already realized, and updated the answer. In previous state of the answer, I should have used `IN` but I think its fine now.

Comment: @deckjohn: Please refer the updated answer. Queries got much simpler by using `LIMIT 1,1` in the inner query.

Comment: Support for LIMIT in a sub query in mysql is limited, I think. :-) Not sure if this will work too.

Comment: @Abhilash: Look at the accepted answer. That kind of limit worked for the OP.

Comment: I think it will work too (I have upvoted it as well). Just that I have faced a few problems with LIMIT in some versions of mysql sub query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select * FROM users 
Where Credits < (Select Max(Credits) From Users)
ORDER BY credits DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: this one is usesful for second highest record